# powershell does not catch Set-Location error

Tags: powershell

Why is error not catched when I use ?

```
  try {
    Set-Location "c:\non-existing-path"
  } catch {
    Write-Host "cannot find path"
  }
```

Comment: Append `-ErrorAction Stop` to the Set-Location line

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can also put `$ErrorActionPreference = "stop"` at the start of your script to make sure any errors go into the `catch`